# How do i set access token without expiration In WSO2IS

Tags: wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I have strange requirement to implement a workaround OAuth2 in WSO2IS

Is there a way to generate OAuth2.0 access token  without expiry in WSO2IS. I understand by default it’s 60 min.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. What you are trying to do is not acceptable as compromised access token could be used forever. Rather, you are encouraged to use Refresh token with Refresh grant type to obtain the new access token. (Refresh tokens may have a longer life time.)
2. If you insist on having this, you can set the `User Access Token Expiry Time` property in the respective Service Provider's OIDC/Oauth settings to the value of the max Long as `9223372036854775807` seconds. This is equivalent to `292471208` years.

Cheers

Comment: thanks a lot , I agree with your thoughts on compromised access token . But this is just for workaround , will not go for prod :-)